# How to welcome new members in a specific "welcome" text channel discord.py?

Tags: discord.py

I want to make a command for my bot in which we can configure the welcome message the bot can send. So, the configuration works like so: `nb welcome <#channel_where_welcome_msg_to_be_shown> <#channel_to_be_mentioned_in_the_welcome_msg>`.

The expected output being an embed where it is written
`Hello <member>! Pls go to <#channel_to_be_mentioned_in_the_welcome_msg> to choose your roles.`

Here is my code:

```py
@client.command(aliases = ["welcome"])
async def _welcome(ctx, channel : discord.TextChannel, roles : discord.TextChannel = None):
    global channel_welcome
    global role_welcome
    channel_welcome = channel
    
    if roles != None:
        role_welcome = roles
        
    else:
        role_welcome = None
    
    await ctx.send("Ok, welcome message configured!")    

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    global channel_welcome
    global role_welcome
    pfp = member.avatar_url
    
    if role_welcome == None:
        embedVar = discord.Embed(title="WELCOME!",description = "{}, you are welcome to this server!" . format(member.mention), color = 0xff9900)
        embedVar.set_thumbnail(url = pfp)
        await client.getchannel(channel_welcome).send(embed = embedVar)

    else:
        embedVar = discord.Embed(title="WELCOME!",description = "{}, you are welcome to this server! Go to {} to assign yourself some roles." . format(member.mention, role_welcome.mention), color = 0xff9900)
        embedVar.set_thumbnail(url = pfp)
        await client.getchannel(channel_welcome).send(embed = embedVar)
```

So, the `welcome` command is the configuration command. As you can see, the `roles` argument is optional and the user can use it if he/she wants.
Whenever I run the code and someone joins the server, it doesn't send the message *or* raises any error.

Any suggestions of how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the bot does not react when a user joins, is probably because you did not define the appropriate intents for the bot.

First of all, you need to go to the [Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications) and enable the `Server Members Intent`
[image: Developer Portal]

Now in the code, you need to define the intents

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents().default()
intents.members = True
client = commands.Bot(prefix = "your_prefix", intents = intents)
```

This will allow the bot to listen to the `on_member_join` events.

Comment: Ok, but can you please explain what intents are? By the way, it worked, thanks!